# Form Casting in Play Framework 2.0.4 with securesocial

Tags: java, scala, playframework, securesocial

Is there a way to cast **play.api.data.Form** to **play.api.data.Form** in Play Framework?

I'm using secure social for play 2.0.4 and I'm having these errors when I compile custom templates.

```
[error] /home/mario/tegik-play/app/controllers/SecureTemplate.scala:19: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[(String, String)]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)]
[error]     views.html.custom.login(form, msg)
[error]                             ^
[error] /home/mario/tegik-play/app/controllers/SecureTemplate.scala:24: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[securesocial.controllers.Registration.RegistrationInfo]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[securesocial.controllers.Registration.RegistrationInfo]
[error]     views.html.custom.Registration.signUp(form, token)
[error]                                           ^
[error] /home/mario/tegik-play/app/controllers/SecureTemplate.scala:28: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[String]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[java.lang.String]
[error]     views.html.custom.Registration.startSignUp(form)
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/mario/tegik-play/app/controllers/SecureTemplate.scala:32: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[String]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[java.lang.String]
[error]     views.html.custom.Registration.startResetPassword(form)
[error]                                                       ^
[error] /home/mario/tegik-play/app/controllers/SecureTemplate.scala:36: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[(String, String)]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)]
[error]     views.html.custom.Registration.resetPasswordPage(form, token)
[error]                                                      ^
[error] /home/mario/tegik-play/app/controllers/SecureTemplate.scala:40: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Form[securesocial.controllers.PasswordChange.ChangeInfo]
[error]  required: play.data.Form[securesocial.controllers.PasswordChange.ChangeInfo]
[error]     views.html.custom.passwordChange(form)
[error]                                      ^
[error] 6 errors found
```

Hope anyone can help me.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

`play.api.data.Form` is the Scala API, while `play.data.Form` is the Java one.
Make sure you're specifying the right package (the first one I guess) in your views.